# Исключение System.AccessViolationException при попытке получить кодеки

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+

Приложение выполняет получение изображений со сканера. При попытке получения кодеков изображений GDI+ возникает исключение:

> 19.01.2015 12:11:06 - System.TypeInitializationException:
>   Инициализатор типа "GdiPlusLib.Gdip"
>   выдал исключение. --->
>   System.AccessViolationException:
>   Попытка чтения или записи в защищенную
>   память. Это часто свидетельствует о
>   том, что другая память повреждена.
>   в
>   System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipGetImageEncodersSize(Int32&
>   numEncoders, Int32& size)    в
>   System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()
>   в GdiPlusLib.Gdip..cctor() в
>   D:\Ivan\ModuleScanWithSVN\mod_scan\mod_scan\TwainGui\GdiPlusLib.cs:строка
>   16    --- Конец трассировки
>   внутреннего стека исключений ---    в
>   GdiPlusLib.Gdip.SaveDIBAs(String
>   picname, IntPtr bminfo, IntPtr pixdat)
>   в
>   TwainGui.MainFrame.System.Windows.Forms.IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage(Message&
>   m) в
>   D:\Ivan\ModuleScanWithSVN\mod_scan\mod_scan\TwainGui\MainFrame.cs:строка
>   464    в
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.ProcessFilters(MSG&
>   msg, Boolean& modified)    в
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.PreTranslateMessage(MSG&
>   msg)    в
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponent.FPreTranslateMessage(MSG&
>   msg)    в
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32
>   pvLoopData)    в
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>   в
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>   в
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form
>   mainForm)    в
>   ThreadedSocket.Server.Scan(String
>   tempPathToUse) в
>   D:\Ivan\ModuleScanWithSVN\mod_scan\mod_scan\TwainGui\Server.cs:строка
>   404    в ThreadedSocket.Server.Main()
>   в
>   D:\Ivan\ModuleScanWithSVN\mod_scan\mod_scan\TwainGui\Server.cs:строка
>   167

GdiPlusLib.cs 16 строка:

```
private static ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
```

.NET Framework 4.5 Win7 x64

**Обновление**

Вопрос в том, с чем связано исключение "System.AccessViolationException: Попытка чтения или записи в защищенную память. Это часто свидетельствует о том, что другая память повреждена.", возникающее при попытке получить кодеки GDI+ следующим образом: `ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();` ? Как возможно исправить проблему? Есть два компа с одинаковой ОС Win 7 и одним framework-ом 4.5.1 - на одном есть проблема при выполнении приложения, а на другом нет такой проблемы.

При этом уже используется готовый код библиотеки

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Drawing.dll
```

[Здесь](http://www.cyberforum.ru/windows-forms/thread933580.html) про подобную проблему пишут - насколько понятно, она в ОС, но где именно неясно.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace GdiPlusLib
{


public class Gdip
{
    private static ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();

    private static bool GetCodecClsid( string filename, out Guid clsid )
    {
        clsid = Guid.Empty;
        string ext = Path.GetExtension( filename );
        if( ext == null )
            return false;
        ext = "*" + ext.ToUpper();
        foreach( ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs )
            {
            if( codec.FilenameExtension.IndexOf( ext ) >= 0 )
                {
                clsid = codec.Clsid;
                return true;
                }
            }
        return false;
    }


    public static bool SaveDIBAs( string picname, IntPtr bminfo, IntPtr pixdat )
    {
            Guid clsid;
            if (!GetCodecClsid(picname, out clsid))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unknown picture format for extension " + Path.GetExtension(picname),
                                "Image Codec", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                return false;
            }

            IntPtr img = IntPtr.Zero;
            int st = GdipCreateBitmapFromGdiDib(bminfo, pixdat, ref img);
            if ((st != 0) || (img == IntPtr.Zero))
                return false;

            st = GdipSaveImageToFile(img, picname, ref clsid, IntPtr.Zero);
            GdipDisposeImage(img);
            return st == 0;
    }




    [DllImport("gdiplus.dll", ExactSpelling=true)]
    internal static extern int GdipCreateBitmapFromGdiDib( IntPtr bminfo, IntPtr pixdat, ref IntPtr image );

    [DllImport("gdiplus.dll", ExactSpelling=true, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern int GdipSaveImageToFile( IntPtr image, string filename, [In] ref Guid clsid, IntPtr encparams );

    [DllImport("gdiplus.dll", ExactSpelling=true)]
    internal static extern int GdipDisposeImage( IntPtr image );

    }

}
```

Comment: @IvanKing, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: при этом уже используется готовый код библиотеки C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Drawing.dll

Comment: @IvanKing: Хм. `GdiPlusLib.Gdip.SaveDIBAs(String picname, IntPtr bminfo, IntPtr pixdat)` — это ваш код?

Comment: @VladD, да.

Comment: @IvanKing: Ну, вы ж в нём работаете с нативной памятью, проблемы вполне возможны.

Приведите код, будем смотреть.

Comment: private static ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders(); уже здесь происходит ошибка - значит проблема не в этом коде

Comment: Вообще идей нет, по какой причине происходит эта ошибка?